# No xml file created after creating activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using intellij idea i have created an activity by clicking on project and then select new and then android component. Activity is created and it is also mentioned in manifest file but i am unable to see its xml file.

Comment: So create one by yourself?

Comment: I have created it myself but how to link this layout file with class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select "new" and then Select "new Android XML file". Then link these two in the android manifest.

Comment: I am using intellij idea i goto src my project name and select new and then android activity bu i am unable to see its layout file

Comment: @MarbleStones: The XML plays no part in the manifest file. It will be referenced in the `Activity` in the `onCreate()` method with the `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_name);` statement. In a `Fragment`, you would inflate it in the `onCreateView()` method

Comment: @SiddharthLele I am also new in android will u please let me know .using intellij idea help me create the design of layout in android